# Laptop only boots to grub> command shell

Tags: boot, laptop, uefi, bootloader, grub2

I've managed to semi-brick a laptop by using it to install Xubuntu to an external drive.
The laptop is a Toshiba Satellite NB10t-A-10F.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

How I got here:

I told Windows 8.1 to reboot to USB stick.
The USB stick contained Xubuntu 18.04.1, which I then installed to a connected external drive, with the bootloader also installing to the external drive.

When rebooting the computer, it only shows the grub command shell (grub>, not grub rescue).
Before reaching this point, it displays the message “System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults.”.
Grub command shell lists (hd0,gpt[1-5]), regardless of how many drives are attached.
Previously, I could still access Windows (and Xubuntu I think) by holding F2 down as the computer turned on. This would bring up the BIOS, cancelling Fast Boot (I think?) and allowing the external drives to initialise. After disabling Secure Boot, exiting the BIOS would make the computer boot to grub and show the entries including Windows and Xubuntu.
Since then, F2 randomly stopped having any effect. F12 has no effect either.

Using grub ls, I can determine only (hd0,gpt2) is readable, is FAT (presumably EFI partition), and consists of the following:

```
(hd0,gpt2)/
(hd0,gpt2)/efi/
(hd0,gpt2)/efi/Microsoft/
(hd0,gpt2)/efi/Microsoft/Boot/
(hd0,gpt2)/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
(hd0,gpt2)/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
(hd0,gpt2)/efi/Microsoft/Boot/[other assorted folders and files]
(hd0,gpt2)/efi/Microsoft/Boot/BCD.LOG1 (I probably made these LOGs     trying to make grub command prompt boot something)
(hd0,gpt2)/efi/Microsoft/Boot/BCD.LOG2
(hd0,gpt2)/efi/Boot/
(hd0,gpt2)/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
(hd0,gpt2)/efi/Boot/fbx64.efi
(hd0,gpt2)/efi/ubuntu/
(hd0,gpt2)/efi/ubuntu/fw/ (empty)
(hd0,gpt2)/efi/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi
(hd0,gpt2)/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
(hd0,gpt2)/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg
(hd0,gpt2)/efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
(hd0,gpt2)/efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
(hd0,gpt2)/efi/ubuntu/bootx64.csv
(hd0,gpt2)/efi/toshiba/
(hd0,gpt2)/efi/toshiba/Boot/
(hd0,gpt2)/efi/toshiba/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
(hd0,gpt2)/efi/toshiba/Boot/bootmgr.efi
(hd0,gpt2)/efi/toshiba/Boot/[other assorted folders and files, but no BCD.LOG files]
(hd0,gpt2)/bootsect.bak
```

So, to sum up, I can no longer access the BIOS, and can only access grub command prompt.

Any hints or insights would be appreciated too. For instance, where would this grub command shell be stored? In the BIOS, or somewhere on the hard disk?

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Here's my disgusting hack solution. I took the hard drive out, and repositioned efipartition/Windows/Boot to efipartition/Ubuntu, and renamed copies of bootmgfw.efi to the names of EFI files previously in efipartition/ubuntu. The computer thinks it's booting from grubx64.efi or something like that, but really it's a Windows EFI. I feel dirty :(